# add Product size to cart (laravel shoppingcart)

Tags: php, laravel, shopping-cart

I have followed a tutorial to create a laravel shopping cart https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jzi6aLKVw-A&list=PLEhEHUEU3x5oPTli631ZX9cxl6cU_sDaR&index=3 and composer https://github.com/hardevine/LaravelShoppingcart
I want make button select  size product

CartController.php

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $duplicates = Cart::search(function ($cartItem, $rowId) use ($request) {
        return $cartItem->id === $request->id;
    });

    if ($duplicates->isNotEmpty()) {
        return redirect()->route('cart.index')->with('success_message', 'Item is already in your cart!');
    }

    Cart::add($request->id, $request->name, 1, $request->price, $request->data)->associate('App\Product');
    return redirect()->route('cart.index')->with('success_message', 'Item was added to your cart!');  
}
```

Product.blade.php

```
                        <h1 class="topic">{{ $product->name}}</h1>
                        <h4>{{ $product->price }}</h4> 

                        <div class="size-b">
                            <div class="title">
                                <h5>Trousers</h5>
                            </div>
                            <form action="{{ route('cart.store') }}" method="POST">
                                {{ csrf_field() }}
                                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $product->id }}" >
                                <input type="hidden" name="name" value="{{ $product->name }}" >
                                <input type="hidden" name="price" value="{{ $product->price }}" >
                                    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic">
                                        <button> <input type="checkbox" name="data" value="S" class="btn btn-secondary"><span>S</span></button>
                                        <button><input type="checkbox" name="data" value="M" class="btn btn-secondary">M</button>
                                        <button><input type="checkbox" name="data" value="L" class="btn btn-secondary">L</button>
                                        <button> <input type="checkbox" name="data" value="XL" class="btn btn-secondary">XL</button>
                                    </div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">ซื้อสินค้า</button>
                            </form>
```

cart.blade.php

```
@if (Cart::count() >0 )
            <h4>{{ Cart::count() }}Item(s) in cart</h4>
            <div class="table-cart-destop">
                @foreach (Cart::content() as $item)
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg">
                            <div class="remove">
                            <form action="{{ route('cart.destroy', $item->rowId) }}" method="POST">
                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                            {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">X</button>
                            </form> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            <div class="image-border">
                                <img src="{{ $item->model->photo1}}" class="img-cart" alt="product-cart">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-5">
                            <div class="content">
                                <h4>{{ $item->model->name}}</h4>
                                <p>{{ $item->model->details}}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg">        
                                <p class="size">size {{ $item->model->data }} </p>      
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg">
                            <div class="quality">
                                <form action="">
                                    <div class="form-row align-items-center">
                                        <div class="col-auto my-1">
                                            <select class="custom-select mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormCustomSelect">
                                                <option selected>1</option>
                                                <option value="1">2</option>
                                                <option value="2">3</option>
                                                <option value="3">4</option>
                                                <option value="3">5</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg">
                           <p class="size">{{ $item->data}}฿</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                @endforeach
                    <div class="tatal">
                        <p>ยอดชำระเงินทั้งหมด</p>
                        <p class="price-tatal">{{ Cart::subtotal() }}฿</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="buy-now">
                        <a href="{{ route('checkout.index') }}">
                        <button type="submit" class=" btn btn-secondary">สั่งซื้อสินค้า</button>
                        </a>
                    </div>
```

I try dd($request->all());

[image]

run php artisan serve --> size product (don't show)